# How to override @url.content in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC application.  After I finished the web site I need to change `@url.content` behavior.

So I need to override `@url.content` in all of my website application.  How can I do it?

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jwplayer.js")"></script>
```

Comment: user1167823 - can i ask a favour?? what exactly is the requirement for the change as this could throw up a few more answers for you?? (for example, do you need to add parameters to @url.content, do you need to grab it as a string, add it to the response stream) etc, etc..

Comment: @jim i need to check this for my images , if the value exist do the default behavior otherwise create new image.

Comment: mhf - so, forgetting the 'logic' as to what the image content is, are you saying that an image 'y' has to be created and shown if image 'x' doesn't exist?? if so, i feel that you'd be better off creating a new Html.Image() override i feel. this override would of course contain absolute or relative paths to the image. i think your choice of Url.Content() is folly in this respect. below is my 'example' of this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MHF,

As mentioned in my comments above, i 'feel' you should create a bespoke html.image() helper, rather than try to override the url.content() helper, given that your problem is related to images, and not url.content() per se. here's how i'd approach this:

```
public static partial class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper,
                                string url,
                                object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return Image(helper, url, null, htmlAttributes);
    }
    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper,
                                    string url,
                                    string altText,
                                    object htmlAttributes)
    {
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("image");

        var path = url.Split('?');
        string pathExtra = "";

        // NB - you'd make your test for the existence of the image here
        // and create it if it didn't exist, then return the path to 
        // the newly created image - for better or for worse!! :)

        if (path.Length > 1)
        {
            pathExtra = "?" + path[1];
        }
        builder.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path[0]) + pathExtra);
        builder.Attributes.Add("alt", altText);
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

useage:

```
@Html.Image("~/content/images/ajax-error.gif", new{@class="error_new"})
```

Now, the above is purely a 'lift' from an old mvc project, with a comment added to give a hint as to what you might do. I haven't tested this in any way, so caveat emptor :)

good luck

Comment: MHF - glad to have helped you out. remember to mark the question as answered in case anyone else is searching for a similar solution. all the best til next time ...

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet here would be just to create another `UrlHelper` Extension Method.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ContentExt(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string Content)
    {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: so i need to change all of my website pages . my website is very large

Comment: @user1167823 I don't know any other way to change the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: @MHF You could do  global search-and-replace.